How can one resize the headers in TableView?
I like to use the TableView to display spreadsheet-like data. (officially introduced in version 12.1)
But consider the following (in version 14.1):
data = {{11, 12, 13, 14}, {21, 22, 23, 24}, {31, 32, 33, 34}, {41, 42, 43, 44}};
colheads = {"TableView", "Needs", "Better", "Documentation"};
roheads = {"First", "second", "Third", "Seventh"}; 
TableView[data, Headers -> {colheads, rowheads}]


The headers are unreadable. The obvious solution is to use the HeaderSize option. However, even in the documentation the singular example has poor results, for instance (not from documentation):
TableView[data, Headers -> {colheads, rowheads}, HeaderSize -> {5, 5}] gives this:

where the actual header boxes aren't modified.
The desired output is like this:

(note that the widths and heights of the non-header rows/columns can be set with ItemSize, though I did not do so here. But that does not suffice for the header rows/columns as far as I can tell)
The question: How can I programmatically make the header rows and columns larger?
related: 213332 216634

We can use FullForm after manually resizing the columns as desired to discover the undocumented Option TableViewBoxHeaderItemSize
TableView[List[List[11,12,13,14],List[21,22,23,24],List[31,32,33,34],
     List[41,42,43,44]],List[Number,String],
Rule[Dividers,List[List[List[Automatic]],List[List[Automatic]]]],
Rule[Headers,List[List["TableView","Needs","Better","Documentation"],List["First","second","Third","Seventh"]]],
Rule[ItemSize,List[Inherited,Inherited]],
Rule[TableViewBoxHeaderItemSize,List[Rule["RowsIndexed",List[Rule[1,6.845836817324155`]]],Rule["ColumnsIndexed",List[Rule[1,1.7871175902128078`]]]]]]

So we can use this directly, even though the syntax highlighting is incorrectly saying that it is not an option (it's red).
TableView[data, Headers -> {colheads, rowheads}, 
 TableViewBoxHeaderItemSize -> {"RowsIndexed" -> {1 -> 7}, (*only 1-> val works?*)
   "ColumnsIndexed" -> {1 -> 2}}]

Produces

as desired. I only noticed an effect when the rule following "ColumnIndexed" or "RowIndexed" was for col/row 1, but since this is the only portion I don't know how to do using ItemSize this is perfectly fine.
